# I have an array with objects. How Can I Implement the transformation?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Array of addressProperties, sagProperties merged and combined into array of validAddress

Input

```
[
     {
        "id": "GIS",
        "href": "",
        "provide": false,
        "date": "2022-04-11T22:05:49.157Z",
        "result": "success",
        "resultDetails": {
            "information": "MATCH",
            "code": "123"
        },
        "@type": "",
        "validAddress": {
            "id": "23243",
            "sNr": "1250",
            "sName": "MIAMI",
            "@sLocation": "",
            "geoSubAddress": [{
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "@type": "",
                "@sLocation": ""
            }],
            "href": "",
            "addressProperties": {
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "centerAbbrName": "MIAMI",
                "taxGeoCode": "0110025092000"
            }
        },
        "submittedAddress": {
            "id": "435353",
            "@type": "",
            "@baseType": "",
            "@sLocation": "",
            "geoSubAddress": [{
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "@type": "",
                "@sLocation": ""
            }],
            "href": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "SagAddress",
        "href": "",
        "provide": false,
        "date": "2022-04-11T22:05:49.157Z",
        "result": "success",
        "resultDetails": {
            "information": "LOCATION",
            "code": ""
        },
        "@type": "",
        "validAddress": {
            "id": "435353",
            "sNr": "1250",
            "sName": "S MIAMI",
            "geoSubAddress": [{
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "@type": "",
                "@sLocation": ""
            }],
            "href": "",
            "sagProperties": {
                "id": "",
                "href": "",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "streetDirection": "",
                "localServingOffice": "",
                "lfacsNpaNxx": ""
            }
        },
        "submittedAddress": {
            "id": "435353",
            "@type": "",
            "@baseType": "",
            "@sLocation": "",
            "geoSubAddress": [{
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "@type": "",
                "@sLocation": ""
            }],
            "href": ""
        }
    }
]
```

Expected output

```
[{
    "id": "",
    "href": "",
    "provide": false,
    "date": "2022-04-11T22:05:49.157Z",
    "result": "success",
    "resultDetails": [{
            "information": "MATCH",
            "code": ""
        },
        {
            "information": "LOCATION",
            "code": ""
        }
    ],
    "validAddress": [{
            "id": "435353",
            "streetNr": "1250",
            "streetName": "",
            "streetType": "",
            "geoSubAddress": [{
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "@type": "",
                "@sLocation": ""
            }],
            "href": "",
            "addressProperties": {
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "baseAddressGlid": "435353",
                "ratecenterAbbrName": "MIAMI",
                "taxGeoCode": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "435353",
            "streetNr": "1250",
            "streetName": "S MIAMI",
            "streetType": "AV",
            "postcode": "33130",
            "geoSubAddress": [{
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "@type": "",
                "@sLocation": ""
            }],
            "href": "",
            "sagProperties": {
                "id": "435353",
                "href": "",
                "houseNumber": "1250",
                "streetDirection": "S",
                "streetName": "MIAMI",
                "lfacsNpaNxx": "305350"
            }
        }
    ],
    "submittedAddress": {
        "id": "435353",
        "@type": "",
        "@baseType": "",
        "@sLocation": "",
        "geoSubAddress": [{
            "id": "435353",
            "href": "",
            "@type": "",
            "@sLocation": ""
        }],
        "href": ""
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first element, remove the address from it, update the id to an empty string, then concatenate a new address with an array of all validAddress values (using the multivalued selector). It seems that same keys need to be renamed inside the validAddress so we can use map() for that.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload[0] - "validAddress") update {
    case id at .id -> ""
} ++ {
            validAddress: payload.*validAddress map {
                id: $.id,
                streetNr: $.sNr,
                streetName: $.sName,
                streetType: "",
                geoSubAddress: $.geoSubAddress,
                href: $.href,
                addressProperties: $.addressProperties
            }
    }
```